# Scale content of fullscreen iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, scale

How can I scale the content of a fullscreen iframe without changing the size of the actual iframe?

This is my current attempt at trying to scale the content, but it ends up canceling out the 100% width and height:

```
<style>
    #frame {
    -ms-zoom: 0.75;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(0.75);
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    position:fixed; 
    top:0px; 
    left:0px; 
    bottom:0px; 
    right:0px;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    border:none; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    z-index:999999; 
    }
</style>
    <iframe src="../index.php" id="frame">
    Your browser doesn't support iframes
</iframe>
```

Is there a way to do this in either javascript or css while keeping the height and width at 100%?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by compensating for the loss from scale in the height and width:

If scale is 75% just set height & width to 133.34%.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have no control whatsoever on what is suppose to happen in the iframe unless you put some javascript listeners in your main page and the source of your iframe.  Its not an easy task.